# How to advertise iTunes Server using dnsmasq

Tags: dnsmasq

How can I advertise an iTunes/DAAP-Server using [dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html)?

None of these entries worked for me:

```
srv-host=_daap._tcp,192.168.1.100,3689
txt-record= _daap._tcp.192.168.1.100,port=3689
```

---

Tried to implement grawity's suggestion this way. No success yet.

```
ptr-record=_daap._tcp.dns-sd-services,"iTunes Server._daap._tcp.dns-sd-services"
srv-host=_daap._tcp,itunes.home,3689
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Not all DNS-SD clients use unicast DNS (unless you specifically ask them.) Even those which do, might require a PTR record named `b._dns-sd._udp` pointing back to the domain. (See [Setting up a Bonjour Name Server](http://www.dns-sd.org/ServerSetup.html).)
2. SRV records *must* point to a *name*. They cannot be pointed to an IP address directly.
3. `_daap._tcp SRV` is not enough; in DNS-SD it must be a PTR record instead, and the SRV/TXT records should be under their own name, e.g. `My library._daap._tcp`. See [Adding DNS-SD Service Discovery Records](http://www.dns-sd.org/ServerStaticSetup.html) for more details.
4. iTunes-published DNS-SD records have a lot more metadata than just the address/port; there are around 11 TXT fields published by default.

```
b._dns-sd._udp          PTR @
lb._dns-sd._udp         PTR @
_daap._tcp              PTR "My library._daap._tcp"
"My library._daap._tcp" SRV 0 0 3689 desktop
                        TXT ( "txtvers=1" "iTSh Version=196616" "Machine Name=....."
                              "Database ID=....." "OSsi=....." "and so on" )
desktop                 A 192.168.1.100
```

Really, just stick with mDNS for service advertisements... doing it manually *will* be a pain. (You can also set up Bonjour to update uDNS records, too, but not with dnsmasq - although bind9 works.)

Comment: Thx for the detailed answer. I'm on a router and afaik there's neither mDNS nor bind9. I tried to implement your explanations (see above). Wasn't sure how to translate #1 to the dnsmasq syntax. Probably that's why it doesn't work yet.

Comment: @user47498: mDNS would be running on the *computers* -- both on the iTunes host, and on client hosts; "Bonjour" for Windows/OSX and "Avahi" for Linux.

Comment: I need to be a little more informative: The server is on the openvpn network over tun. When I advertise it using dns-sd (on the Mac) I see the tracks in the local iTunes.app. The question came up because I'd like to do the advertising *once* on the router instead of doing it on the client each time before accessing the library.